# make a div appear and disappear between 2 heights on scroll down - - and reverse on scroll up

Tags: javascript, html, css

In an earlier thread ([How to make a div appear and disappear between 2 heights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087078/how-to-make-a-div-appear-and-disappear-between-2-heights)) I found a script to add to my html that makes a div appear at a specified height then disappear at a second specified height.

Unfortunately, when I scroll up, the divs all remain showing - they don't disappear in the same order they appeared.

Anyone know if there's a way to modify this script so that a div (with an id two_b) that has a fixed position is visible when and only when the user is scrolling between 632px and 3352px from the top of the page?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#two_b").hide();
        $(window).scroll(function(){
              if($(window).scrollTop()>632){
                 if($(window).scrollTop()>3352){
                    $("#two_b").fadeOut();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    $("#two_b").fadeIn();
                 }
              }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's the site I'm working on. It's for educational purposes and not approved by Theo Chocolate: http://www.saritaschaffer.com/wp

New version after Eyal's suggestion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#two_b").hide();
        $(window).scroll(function(){
               if($(window).scrollTop()>632 && $(window).scrollTop()>3352){
                $("#two_b").fadeOut();
             }
         else
             {
                $("#two_b").fadeIn();
              }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try adjusting your if condition:  `var t = $(window).scrollTop(); if(t > 632 && t < 3352)) {$("#two_b").fadeIn();} else {$("#two_b").fadeOut();}`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you nested the if statements.

Replace:

```
          if($(window).scrollTop()>632){
             if($(window).scrollTop()>3352){
                $("#two_b").fadeOut();
             }
             else{
                $("#two_b").fadeIn();
             }
          }
```

With:

```
         if($(window).scrollTop()>632 && $(window).scrollTop()<3352){
            $("#two_b").fadeIn();
         }
         else{
            $("#two_b").fadeOut();
         }
```

What happened was that for the elements to fade out they scrollTop position must be bigger than 632 and smaller than 3352. 
To achieve your goal you need to unite those statements and put the else if either of them is false.

Comment: Sweet- I'll try that, Eyal!

Comment: You've got `> 3352` rather than `< 3352` and `fadeOut()` where you should `fadeIn()`

Comment: I switched it out but it still seems to be there when you scroll back up. Maybe I didn't copy & paste exactly right? Here's what it looks like now - I'll paste into my original post.

Comment: Thank you, Eyal and adamdc78! I'll try those changes!

Comment: Magnificent! Works beautifully! Thanks so much, guys! Reveals and conceals everything right where I wanted! www.saritaschaffer.com/wp :)